# I want to call a function when user submit a form in codeignitor http://localhost/abc/categories/sub_categories/add_sub_categories

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, url

I have a categories controller and inside the categories controller i have two function one is displaying all the the sub categories and also display a form for adding a new sub category but a user click on add button it is not forwarding the url this location "http://localhost/abc/categories/sub_categories/" to "http://localhost/abc/categories/sub_categories/add_sub_categories" .

```
<?php 
      $attributes = array('method' => 'POST');
      echo form_open('categories/sub_categories/add_sub_category',$attributes);
 ?>
```

Comment: Lots of hits for a web search on "call a function when user submit a form in codeignitor". You should show your research as an [edit] and tell us what is unique in your case.

Comment: What is the value assigned to `$config['base_url']` in  /application/config/config.php ?

Comment: CodeIgniter uses a [segment-based approach](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#uri-segments) to URLs. The URL you show does not appear to follow that scheme.

Comment: Every thing is working perfect i have set the base url but thank you it was a problem in form action basically the action url was submitting it to the same page